# VS2012 Preventing Data Loss SQL Server Project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I'm working for the first time using VS2012 to build and deply a SQL Server 2012 project. I successfully created a database and published as a data-tier application.

The issue I have is how to prevent data loss from occurring on an update. For some reason, I cannot find the "Block incremental deployment if data loss might occur" option in Visual Studio.

I do see it in the "Debug" tab under Project > Properties, but I think I'm missing a "Deployment" tab? From my understanding, the settings in "Debug" only affect debugging. How do I get the deployment options to appear? I tried checking the prevent data loss box in "Debug" but it causes data loss on my test publish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was a misunderstanding on my part. The option was actually working as intended, despite being placed under "Debug" in the menu.

The way I was testing it was by renaming a table with some data. What I didn't realize was that the publish was just adding a new table to the database, not dropping the old one. Hence, no data loss actually occurred.

I received the warning using Schema Compare as expected.